# How to use RouteReuseStartegy API in Angular 5 to reinitialize the component when URL is changed from /detail/2 to /detail/3?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

Currently when my URL is changed from `/detail/2` to `detail/3`, the DetailComponent's lifecycle hooks (ngOnInit etc.) are not called again.

RouteReuseStrategy has a function `shouldReuseRoute()` but I dont know how to use it to solve my purpose.

Comment: Specifically, I need to implement RouteResuseStrategy in Angular5 as used in 
https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, you have to inject "ActivatedRoute" service of router library. this is the code for ngOnInit of your DetailComponent's

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
```

}

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
  (param: ParamMap) => {
    this.departmentId = parseInt(param.get('id'));
  }
);
```

}

In param map you will get change in param id.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this is not the recommended way. Because what if I want all lifecycle hooks of that component to run again we cant call every method in subscribe.
In a nutshell, I need Angular 5 version of https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5